# select last child of element that does not have a certain class

Tags: jquery, css

I am try to select the last element of a child that does not have a certain class. I have setup a [`js fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/VATaj/2).

```
<aside class="col2">
    <div class="infobox teal"></div>
    <div class="infobox mediumbrown"></div>
    <div class="quotebox"></div>
    <div class="quotebox"></div>
</aside>
```

I have tried:

```
$("aside.col2 div:last").not(".quotebox").addClass("last-round");
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't include script tags in the js section of jsfiddle.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to do the `not` prior to the `last`:

```
$("aside.col2 div:not('.quotebox'):last")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VATaj/1/

Comment: @digitalbart To mark this answer as "works like a charm" click the green tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("aside.col2 div:last:not(.infobox)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("aside.col2 div").not('.quotebox').last();
```

Comment: That doesn't give you the last one WITHOUT the `quotebox` class.

Comment: $("aside.col2 div").not('.quotebox').last(); should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
$("aside.col2 :not(.quotebox)").last().addClass("last-round");
```

Select all of the ones that don't have the class, THEN get the last one.